# Spark in Scala - Map with Function with Extra Arguments

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Is there a way in Scala to define an explicit function for an RDD Transformation with additional/extra arguments?

For example, the Python code below uses a lambda expression to apply the transformation map (requiring a function with one argument) with the function my_power (actually having 2 arguments).

```
def my_power(a, b):
    res = a ** b
    return res

def my_main(sc, n):
    inputRDD = sc.parallelize([1, 2, 3, 4])
    powerRDD = inputRDD.map(lambda x: my_power(x, n))
    resVAL = powerRDD.collect()
    for item in resVAL:
        print(item)
```

However, when attempting an equivalent implementation in Scala, I get a Task not serializable exception.

```
val myPower: (Int, Int) => Int = (a: Int, b: Int) => {
  val res: Int = math.pow(a, b).toInt
  res
}

def myMain(sc: SparkContext, n: Int): Unit = {
  val inputRDD: RDD[Int] = sc.parallelize(Array(1, 2, 3, 4))
  val squareRDD: RDD[Int] = inputRDD.map( (x: Int) => myPower(x, n) )
  val resVAL: Array[Int] = squareRDD.collect()
  for (item <- resVAL){
    println(item)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this way it was working for me.

```
package examples

import org.apache.log4j.Level
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object RDDTest extends App {
  val logger = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger("org")
  logger.setLevel(Level.WARN)
  val spark = SparkSession.builder()
    .appName(this.getClass.getName)
    .config("spark.master", "local[*]").getOrCreate()


  val myPower: (Int, Int) => Int = (a: Int, b: Int) => {
    val res: Int = math.pow(a, b).toInt
    res
  }
  val scontext = spark.sparkContext
  myMain(scontext, 10);

  def myMain(sc: SparkContext, n: Int): Unit = {
    val inputRDD: RDD[Int] = sc.parallelize(Array(1, 2, 3, 4))
    val squareRDD: RDD[Int] = inputRDD.map((x: Int) => myPower(x, n))
    val resVAL: Array[Int] = squareRDD.collect()
    for ( item <- resVAL ) {
      println(item)
    }
  }
}
```

Result :

```
1024
59049
1048576
```

There is another option to broadcast n  using `sc.broadcast` and access in the closure like map is also possible...

Answer (score 0):

Simply adding a local variable as a function alias made it work:

```
val myPower: (Int, Int) => Int = (a: Int, b: Int) => {
  val res: Int = math.pow(a, b).toInt
  res
}

def myMain(sc: SparkContext, n: Int): Unit = {
  val inputRDD: RDD[Int] = sc.parallelize(Array(1, 2, 3, 4))

  val myPowerAlias = myPower
  val squareRDD: RDD[Int] = inputRDD.map( (x: Int) => myPowerAlias(x, n) )

  val resVAL: Array[Int] = squareRDD.collect()
  for (item <- resVAL){
    println(item)
  }
}
```

Comment: above approach which i mentioned not working for you ?